# FileNotFoundError even though condition needs to be passed before renaming

Tags: python, path, file-rename, pathlib, python-os

I am writing a script that should automate the moving and renaming of a huge amount of pdf files. The files are initially downloaded in a temporary directory, the path where they were initially downloaded is saved in a json file. The files definitely exist in the source location I indicate in the script, I even use the same variables that pass the condition that checks that the file exists before trying to rename, and I still get a `FileNotFoundError` .

My code:

```
def distribute(source, title_journal, year_of_issue, volume_and_issue, title): # title_journal, year_of_issue and volume_and_issue are just strings of directory names

    root_destination = os.path.join(package_path, "Downloads") # package_path = working directory (os.getcwd()), "Downloads" = parent directory where files will be moved
    journal_destination = os.path.join(root_destination, title_journal) 
    year_destination = os.path.join(journal_destination, year_of_issue)
    file_destination = os.path.join(volume_destination, title)
    volume_destination = os.path.join(year_destination, volume_and_issue)
    current_path_to_file = source
    file_destination = os.path.join(volume_destination, f”{title}.pdf”)
    os.rename(current_path_to_file, file_destination)


current_path = Path(dictionary["Download_path"]) # is an absolute path to the file's current location
    if current_path.is_file():
        distribute(current_path, journal, year, volume, next(iter(dictionary)))
```

Example of Error (edited to show variables in my script):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Documents/run1/Downloads/Temporary_folder/09567976211043428.pdf' -> '/Users/me/Documents/Downloads/journal_title/year_of_issue/volume_and_issue/new_file_name'
```

Comment: Go through each of the ```*_destination``` paths and check if they exist.  What is package_path?

Comment: @ewong `package_path` is an absolute path to the directory where the "Downloads" directory will be. I get it when I first run the script with `os.getcwd()`. So it's my working directory. I am not sure what you mean. This is part of a `for` loop that loops over every dictionary (`dictionary` variable in my script) in a json file. Every dictionary contains the info for its corresponding pdf file (including where it currently is - `dictionary["Download_path"]`. Am I not already doing that?

Comment: @KJ can you explain more what you mean? What do you mean by absolute truth? I am using mac os. I don’t understand how the path could be the problem if it passes the condition of its existence before trying to rename it. Is your comment about that?

Comment: @KJ Which folder do you mean? If you mean the folder in the`volume_destination` path in my script, I have just checked with a pathlib `is_dir()` method and the folder is found. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/Users/me/Documents/Downloads` already exists, the error is telling you that one or more of the directories `journal_title/year_of_issue/volume_and_issue` within that directory do not exist, and will not be created implicitly.

The usual solution is to call `os.makedirs` with `exist_ok=True` to make sure the destination directory structure exists.

```
    file_destination = os.path.join(volume_destination, f"{title}.pdf")
    os.makedirs(volume_destination, exist_ok=True) # <------
    os.rename(current_path_to_file, file_destination)
```

Tangentially, notice also that I had to change the curly "typographer" double quotes to proper ASCII double quotes.