# shutil.move FileNotFound error in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, shutil

I have a dataset that is uploaded to my google drive. I have mounted my drive to google colab. I am trying to change the directory structure of my dataset to comply with yolov5 acceptable structure. In my colab notebook, I have made directories (created in my drive) for images, labels and for each of these folders: train, test and val. Using sklearn train test split I already split the dataset into train test and validation. Now I am trying to move these files to my new created directories/folder using the following code but I am getting errors that I cant understand:

```
 # Split the dataset into train-valid-test splits 
 train_images, val_images, train_annotations, val_annotations = 
 train_test_split(images, annotations, test_size = 0.2, random_state =1)
 val_images, test_images, val_annotations, test_annotations = 
 train_test_split(val_images, val_annotations, test_size = 0.5, 
 random_state = 1)


 #Utility function to move images 
 def move_files_to_folder(list_of_files, destination_folder):
     for f in list_of_files:
       try:
          shutil.move(f, destination_folder)
       except:
           print(f)
           assert False

 # Move the splits into their folders
 
move_files_to_folder(train_images, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/images/train')
move_files_to_folder(val_images, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/images/val')
move_files_to_folder(test_images, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/images/test')
move_files_to_folder(train_annotations, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask- 
monitoring-dataset/labels/train')
move_files_to_folder(val_annotations, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/labels/val')
move_files_to_folder(test_annotations, '/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/labels/test')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
video_12_02_2022_400591.jpg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    565     try:
--> 566         os.rename(src, real_dst)
    567     except OSError:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'video_12_02_2022_400591.jpg' -> 
'/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring- 
dataset/images/train/video_12_02_2022_400591.jpg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'video_12_02_2022_400591.jpg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-6a0bf31cd68d> in move_files_to_folder(list_of_files, destination_folder)
      6         except:
      7             print(f)
----> 8             assert False
      9 
     10 # Move the splits into their folders

AssertionError:
```

Note: My current directory is '/content/drive/My Drive/FYP/covid-facemask-monitoring-dataset/

Comment: Have you ensure that the `train_images` and the other variables are containing the **ABSOLUTE PATH** of every images respective to the variables?? Because you are currently at `/content`, you can't simply just put the file names, you need full absolute path.

Comment: However, there's easier way to move dir... you can simply use bash script command `!mv [dir the images currently inside] [the new one you wish to move them to]`

Comment: @DhanaD. Well train_images cant contain the absolute paths because they contain the images that I got after using sklearns's train test split method. here is the line of code: train_images, val_images, train_annotations, val_annotations = train_test_split(images, annotations). That being said I cant just move the directory, I have to move the files in train_images, val_images etc to the respective directories

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399687/filenotfounderror-even-though-condition-needs-to-be-passed-before-renaming/72456374#72456374